# ZURB Foundation: CDN foundation.min.js with fallback to local

Tags: zurb-foundation

I want to load a CDN version of foundation.min.js with a local fallback. The question is: **How can I detect if foundation.js is loaded?**

I saw it done done with jQuery, modernizr, Bootstrap ... but I can't find the code for Foundation.
It should look like this except the part "*window.Foundation*":

```
<!-- jsDelivr CDN -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/4.3.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fallback to local -->
<script>window.Foundation || document.write('<script src="/js/vendor/foundation.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, it turned out that my original code was actually correct. Foundation is actual JavaScript object and I had a typo somewhere else. So, to sum up ... you can load foundation.min.js from CDN with a local fallback like this:

```
<!-- jsDelivr CDN -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/4.3.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fallback to local -->
<script>window.Foundation || document.write('<script src="/js/vendor/foundation.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

If anyone is interested I've created the gist with CDN/local fallback for all Foundation required files:
[gist.github.com/kevinwake/6208601](https://gist.github.com/kevinwake/6208601)

Comment: that gist 404s for me

Answer (score 1):

[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) might be one option for you.

From sections 4.6.2 and 4.6.3 at http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pathsfallbacks

```
requirejs.config({
//To get timely, correct error triggers in IE, force a define/shim exports check.
enforceDefine: true,
paths: {
    jquery: [
        'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min',
        //If the CDN location fails, load from this location
        'lib/jquery'
    ]
}
});

//Later
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
});
```

This above code will try the CDN location, but if that fails, fall back to the local lib/jquery.js location.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer David. I've found out that my original code was actually correct and I can do it without the need for another js library.